# Google Analytics (or Tags): With an event, how to trigger an action in another system?

Tags: google-analytics, tags, analytics, google-tag-manager

I am looking for something that would enable me to trigger an action in another system (a CRM).
For this, ideally, I would like Google Analytics (or Google Tag Manager) to notify the other system the event of shopping cart abandonment.
Assuming I am using customer tracking id, I would like to know a few parameter values.

How can this be implemented? Is this feature provided by GA or GTM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could do that with GA, if your CRM have support for incoming email as notification option.

Basically you could give an event value of -1 for your abandonment event and set up a Custom alert firing on negative value of your event (for example - set alert for Action "Abandon" and condition - value less than 1). Anyhow, this is just example setup, there are many option.

Set email notification for your alert (don't forget to set it for daily) and you are done.